# Fourier Sine Transform - modified Bessel function

Tags: fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I am trying to calculate the following Fourier sine transform:

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty}\, \frac{e^{-y \sqrt{b^2+\xi^2}}}{\xi} \,\sin(x\,\xi)\,d\xi
\end{equation}
with $b>0$ and $y>0$.

Bateman in his book "Tables of integral transforms" Vol. 1 (pp. 16, Eq. (26)) gives that:

\begin{equation}
g(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty}\, e^{-y \sqrt{b^2+\xi^2}}\,\cos(x\,\xi)\,d\xi=\frac{y\,b}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,K_1[b \sqrt{x^2+y^2}]
\end{equation}
where $K_1[]$ is 1st order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

It appears that $\partial_x{f(x,y)}=g(x,y)$. However, I cannot find the primitive of $g(x,y)$.

Has anyone seen this integral before? Any ideas would be appreciated.